# I got a Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, nullreferenceexception

I got this error when I click on SAVE button  inside the save button is
The error is

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
Protected Sub btnWizardFinish_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If (rdoAprovalList.SelectedIndex = 1) Then
        SaveConsideration(4)
    Else
        SaveConsideration(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

and this is save sub that contain to save and update a value in DocumentStatusID field in Database

```
Private Sub SaveConsideration(ByVal DocumentStatusID As Integer)
    Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Try
        If ((txtProducerID.Text.Trim.Length = 9)) Then

            cmd.Connection = Conn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "spConsiderationSaving"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@libDocumentID", txtProducerID.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProducerComments", txtProducerComment.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentStatusID", DocumentStatusID)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConProduceThai", chkConproduceThai.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConProducePolicy", chkConProducePolicy.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConProduceIP", chkConProduceIP.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConProduceDanger", chkConProduceDanger.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConProducePeople", chkConproducePeople.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConProduceManage", chkConProduceManage.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConProduceMade", chkConProduceMade.Checked)
            Conn.Open()
            Dim ResponseText As Integer = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar, Int32).ToString
            If (ResponseText = 1) Then
                lblResponseResult.Text = "<img src='../images/icons/message-boxes/confirmation.png' /> บันทึกลงฐานข้อมูลเรียบร้อยแล้ว"
                If (DocumentStatusID = 3) Then 'Goto next step
                    AlertRedirects("redirect", pnlHint.ClientID, 3, "Verification.aspx")
                Else
                    AlertBoxs("alert", pnlHint.ClientID, 2)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
            sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
            sb.Append("javascript:history.back();return false;")
            sb.Append("};")
            sb.Append("</script>")
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "back", sb.ToString())
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("Error Save: " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        Conn.Close()

    End Try

End Sub
```

I think it's a problem with reference to  something

Comment: please post exact error

Comment: I added an exact error

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: If you don't know what line it happens on then debug it to find out.

Answer (score 2):

what is the error please specify that. the code which you posted in that is seems two syntax mistakes

```
  Dim ResponseText As Integer = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar, Int32).ToString
        If (ResponseText = 1)
```

you are assigning ResponseText a string value which is an integer
and second is if condition there should be double equals like `If (ResponseText == 1)` because it's not assignment single equals used for assignment

Comment: the error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: check by correcting the above error which i mentioned